# Test logic inside subscribe block

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'd like to test the logic inside the subscribe block of this service method in the ngOnInit().

The code below says the method is never called.

How can I test this?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.someMethod.subscribe((res) => {
    if (res.name === 'Bob') {
      this.doSomething();
    }
  });
}
```

**spec**

```
it('should call doSomething on subscribe', () => {
  const doSomethingSpy = spyOn(component, 'doSomething');
  spyOn(component['someService'], 'someMethod').and.returnValue(of());
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(doSomethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using callFake and returning a value with 'name' property should satisfy the if condition

```js
spyOn(component['someService'], 'someMethod').and.callFake(() => of({name: 'Bob'}));
```